# How to Query ContentNote in Apex and show it in LWC Component

Tags: lightning-web-components, soql, contentnote

I am running the below SOQL to query to show 5 to 10 Notes records on in a LWC component based on certain conditions

```
SELECT Id, Title, LatestPublishedVersion.VersionNumber, LatestPublishedVersion.VersionData,
(SELECT LinkedEntityId, LinkedEntity.Name FROM ContentDocumentLinks)
FROM ContentDocument
WHERE FileType = 'SNOTE'
AND LastModifiedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:7
```

I want to show Notes related to an contract on Quotes based on the Contracts picked on a Quote.(could be 1 or many)

When I run the above SOQL i get output like below for the Version Data field

[image]

I get a URL to the actual notes and not the actual notes.

I can do a rest call within salesforce to get the contents but

1. Is there no other elegant or easy way to do it like how we query body field of attachment object in SOQL directly?
2. How do we pass this data to LWC? Is it as a text attribute? If yes will that in any way affect the formatting of the text as  notes is a rich text area field in UI?

Comment: Have you tried getRecords from LWC?

Comment: i will try @sfdcfox, i have to combine fields from 2 objects for for starters i think the idea is still worth a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the tip from @sfdcfox,

Using get records you can get versiondata from content version object and show it in UI. Just showing relevant code, finally the data from server needs to be decoded to string before it is passed to a UI component,

> lighting formatted rich text

in our case.

```
const FIELDS = ['contentversion.Id', 'contentversion.VersionData','contentversion.Title'];

 @wire(getRecords, {
        records: [
            {
              recordIds: ['0687h000002JcT6AAK'],
              fields: FIELDS
            }
        ]
    })

 this.richtext = atob(data.results[0].result.fields.VersionData.value);
```